# What would be the best battery someone could make in the late 1400's?

Tags: engineering, vehicles

In my champaign a character has the ability to gain knowledge from the far future and has used that knowledge to expand technology and bring on an early industrial revolution. They have built up to a point of working with internal combustion engines, and has been searching for a way to make batteries capable of supplying these engines with electricity.

What would be the best battery he could make using materials which which could be obtained using mining tools and techniques avaliable in the 1400's?

Would vehicles (including tanks) even need batteries if they do not have electrical systems (headlights, radios, etc) and the only part of the vehicle using power is the spark plugs?

Comment: The title of your question is asking for a completely different thing than the body. Please choose 1.

Comment: How big are your tanks/vehicles?

Comment: @L.Dutch Thanks, I got distracted and forgot to actually ask the main question, I fixed it.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. They would probably stay between the size of a Renault FT and a Panzer 4. The only important part would be armor strong enough to sustain fire from weapons the size of muskets to as large as a field cannon.

Comment: Diesel engines don't have spark plugs. On the other hands, crank starting a diesel engine is basically impossible, unless it's a very small engine...

Comment: Why would be ordinary lead-acid batteries impossible to make in the 15th century? Please show that you did some research before asking the question.

Comment: @TheEmperorProtects even a half inch of ordinary iron cladding would stop an ordinary musket a ball (hell, a half inch of bronze would do the job), a direct hit from a field cannon could do damage to even a modern tank but that doesn't really mater, because the chances of hitting a moving target with a field cannon other than by sheer fluke are very minimal, they're not exactly designed to track moving objects.

Comment: @AlexP *"crank starting a diesel engine is basically impossible, unless it's a very small"* // this is where you'd use a smaller starter engine that you **can** crank start to crank & start the main engine for you, really not a problem, merely a design issue, I'd personally go for the battery though.

Comment: Why would he be limited to the *"tools and techniques available in the 1400's"* when he's already *"built up to a point of working with internal combustion engines?"* // that aside a quack step through Wikipedia links will show you he doesn't need anything more accept for crude oil extraction for plastic for the casing (or fuel) but that hardly matters as the case doesn't need to be plastic (& bio-diesel (vegetable oil) or distilled alcohol works just fine as fuel.).

Comment: I'm with @Pelinore. I've downvoted the question because it doesn't make sense. (a) Knowledge is available from the future and (b) internal combustion requires fairly advanced knowledge of chemistry. Consequently, the limitation of only 1400s tech doesn't make any sense. Think about it, your medieval people seem to understand what the engine is for, and they know they need a battery... the question just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: With knowledge from the far future, why would the protagonist steer society in the dead end of internal combustion?

Answer (score 1):

**What battery can he make?**

If he's got the knowledge, manpower & resources he can make anything he has the materials for.

A [Nickel–iron battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel%E2%80%93iron_battery) or an ordinary [Lead-acid car battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery) should be within his reach, which isn't to say he's going to be able to churn them out in modern industrial quantities at the start, of course. Though probably without the plastic casing, at least not initially.

A simple [Dynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo) can be used to charge them, perhaps driven by a water mill initially.

He just has to make sure he knows what raw materials he needs and where they can be found, then assuming he has the wealth or power (a local lords ear or sufficient gold) to get them, then he's golden.

**Does he need one?**

No, not really. The [alternator](http://Alternator) should provide for the spark adequately once the engines running, so if hand cranks are fine with him he doesn't need one.